# Is this noun definite

Tags: definite-article

I wrote:

> Automatic **grammar** development can be done by extracting **the grammar** from a Treebank which has an implicit representation of the target grammar

"grammar" just mentioned in "automatic grammar development". Does this make it definite so that I use "the grammar" in the next occurrence shown.

Comment: **grammar** in the first instance is an adjective, not a noun. If you had done this, it would be different: Development of an automatic grammar or Automatic development of a grammar....  (not sure which you mean but at least you'd have given us a noun, grammar).   Development of an automatic grammar can be done by extracting a representation of the grammar from a Treebank.

Comment: But in everyday speech, it would probably fly: *Slow chicken cooking can be done by placing the chicken in a Crock-Pot.*   The first instance of **chicken** is not "definite", it merely establishes the topic of discourse, and thus the definite article is licensed, because all "chicken cooking" requires **a** chicken, and **the** chicken is the required chicken, the inescapable chicken, the chicken you have in your kitchen when following the Crock-Pot recipe.

Comment: But I would add that the sentence *Slow chicken cooking can be done by placing the chicken in a Crock-Pot.* flies no better than a chicken can.  "can be done by placing...." is almost a flightless bird of a verb-phrase. More idiomatic would be: "To cook a chicken slowly, use a Crock-Pot or "Cooking a chicken slowly can be done with a Crock-Pot".

Comment: *Lake crossing can be done by swimming*  versus "You can swim across a lake."  or  "To get to the other side of a lake, you can swim across."  The first is grammatical but hardly idiomatic.

Comment: @TRomano thank you! in fact the context is "*During last decades, many efforts  have been taken for automatic or semi-automatic grammar development. Automatic grammar development  can be done by extracting..*", in the next sentence I tried to address one way for automatic grammar development (development a grammar automatically) and put it in the subject, if you can rephrase it, would like to know your suggestion.

Comment: I do not know what it means "to *develop* a grammar", and your next phrase does not really give me any further clear information, since it says grammar development can be "done" by "extracting" the grammar from a Treebank.   So it would appear that "developing" a grammar is accomplished by "extracting" it from a place where it already exists. How is extraction development?

Comment: @TRomano what about *Automatic grammar development means that a
system extracts a grammar from a Treebank which
has an implicit Treebank grammar.*, this is a sentence from another paper and I tried to rephrase it but it seems I distorted the meaning.

Comment: The paper is redefining "development" as "extraction".  It's like saying *Slow chicken cooking means that a person purchases a pre-cooked rotisserie chicken from a supermarket which has a display case.*  Redefining development as extraction makes no more sense to me than redefining cooking as purchasing.

Comment: @TRomano I see, I wrote *During last decades, many efforts  have been taken for automatic or semi-automatic grammar development. A grammar can be automatically extracted from a Treebank which has an implicit representation of that grammar*

Comment: The second sentence is okay but it is not clear what you mean by "has an *implicit* representation" --"stores a representation"?  And "efforts taken *for*" -- instead of a prepositional phrase *for X*, one would normally expect a to-infinitive complement (e.g. '... efforts taken to speed | enhance | enable | facilitate | support semi-automatic grammar something-or-other').  I'm still dubious that "development" is the right word for that something-or-other, since the grammar seems to exist already in the Treebank.

Comment: When you write "automatic grammar development" do you mean "automatic development using grammars" or "automatic development of grammars"?

Comment: @TRomano I see your point is about *development*, but what one can say? *construction*? or maybe *generation*? And I mean *automatic generation of grammars*, in computational linguistics there are various formalism for the syntax of a language (grammar generates valid sentences), a Treebank is a collection of parsed sentences according to a grammar, then the grammar is implicit in these parsed sentences and one can try to factor it out.

Comment: Ah, that clears it up.  The Treebank doesn't contain a grammar but a set of grammatical statements from which a grammar can be derived or educed. So you might substitute *derivation* for *development*.